# Second city - a lot of turns for simple production

Tags: civilization-6

I am new to Civ games and started straight from 6.

After establishing second city  I've  noticed that number of turns required to produce a building or unit is huge!

E.g.
50 turns to produce a Builder.

How to redecue those numbers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each building, district, wonder, unit or project has a cost (generally refereed as `hammers` by their symbol).

To build something your city needs to produce the required hammers. The time to build something therefore is `cost in hammers / hammers produced per turn`.

There are a lot of ways to influence the hammers your city produces. This is a small list of the most common factors:

- Tiles around your city (when `worked` i.e. with a green population symbol on it). Some tiles (like `hills`) will produce hammers. Some others (like `greenland flats`) won't
- Improved tiles. Your `Builder` units can build `Improvements` on tiles (like `mines`) which improve the hammers provided
- Buildings in your city producing hammers (`water mill`, `workshop`, `factory`, ...)
- Trade routes you initiated from this city can provide hammers. (This is a good strategy to boost a new city)
- Some religions and pantheons provide hammers.

Comment: If you want to see the yields of hexes, enable the "Show Yields" options over the mini map, it really helps and I personally can't imagine playing the game without it on.

Comment: Indirectly, more citizens will also provide more hammers (work more tiles).  So as the city grows it will build stuff faster.

Comment: Builders in particular also become more expensive as you build more of them, so if this is a fairly late new city, you will have a double whammy of high hammer cost and low production. Also wanted to highlight Nijin22's point that Trade routes to cities with well-developed industrial zones will give you an immediate boost in production, and this can be planned for in advance to move a bunch of traders in as soon as the city is founded so you can start many trade routes immediately. This can also help with other yields (food, culture) that a new city finds itself short on.